# How to use custom fingerprints using the sentry sdk for Rust?

Tags: rust, sentry

I would like to set a custom fingerprint for my events using the sentry **SDK for Rust**,
but I could not find any examples on how to do it.

The [official documentation](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/rust/usage/) lacks any mention of *SDK fingerprinting* (unlike the documentation for other platforms).

I also found a [github issue](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-docs/issues/7611) stating that the documentation is missing this bit.

Does anyone have any examples to share?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging, I found this example directly from the [sentry-rust](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-rust/blob/dfdb7b638631bfa0a78b69a51f1f83eb64ab6a62/sentry/examples/message-demo.rs#L8) repository:

```
fn main() {
    let _sentry = sentry::init(sentry::ClientOptions {
        release: sentry::release_name!(),
        debug: true,
        ..Default::default()
    });
    sentry::configure_scope(|scope| {
        scope.set_fingerprint(Some(["my custom fingerprint"].as_ref()));
        scope.set_tag("foo", "bar");
    });

    sentry::capture_message("my message", sentry::Level::Warning);
}
```

which seems to work in my case.

Comment: Note that this means the fingerprint is changed on the current scope, affecting all 'capture' calls you make during that scope. Look at `with_scope` to change only within the callback duration. Or a 'local scope', if Rust has that, is an argument to `capture` methods with a callback that allows you to change the scope for that single capture